# how to fix Objects are not valid as a React child object promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I create an eLearning app using react and want to split routes to many users (pupils, teachers, and admins) so I use this method

NewRoute.js

```
const NewRoute = ({
    component: Component,
    type: type,
    ...rest
}) => (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={ async props => {
            console.log(await CT.checkType(type));
            return CT.checkType(type) === false ? (
                <Redirect to='/login' />
            ) : (
                <Component {...props} />
            )
        }
        }
    />
);
```

checkType.js

```
export default {
  checkType: async (type) => {
    try{
      const res = await axios.get('/api/check/');
      console.log('api response',res);
      return true
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: the function you're using inside `render` is async, meaning it's returning a Promise rather than a React Component. This promise is the `invalid object` the error message is referring to. You cannot feed `render` a function that returns a Promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

You are getting this error because you are passing an async function to `render`, wich is a `Promise` object. You need to pass a React component. This means that this check `CT.checkType(type) === false` cannot be an async call.

So what you are trying to do is not possible.

If you want to render a component based on a request where is what you need.

You need to state that checks the following:

- Check if it's loading
- Check if it's valid or not

So you first set that the route is loading (rendering some Loading component).
When the promise is done, you set is loading to false and set if it's valid or not, wich will return `Redirect` or `Component`.

I have done a very [simple gist](https://gist.github.com/EduVencovsky/f8f6c275f42f7352571c92a59309e31d) for this situation, but the logic is kind of this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...otherProps }) => {

    const { isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useContext(AuthContext)

    return (
        <Route
            {...otherProps}
            render={props => (
                !isLoading
                    ?
                    (
                        isAuthenticated
                            ?
                            <Component {...props} />
                            :
                            <Redirect to={otherProps.redirectTo ? otherProps.redirectTo : '/signin'} />
                    )
                    :
                    <Loading />
            )}
        />
    )

}
```

And inside the `AuthContext` it calls a method that set `isAuthenticated` and `isLoading` based on async requests.